# Combine two raster datasets from different areas - xarray

Tags: python, raster, rioxarray, combine, xarray

I simply wish to combine two raster datasets from different spatial extents and with different coordinate reference systems using python. Eventually, I wish to combine enumerable datasets, but considering parsimony, two will suffice.

Raster1 is EPSG 32616 and Raster 2 is EPSG 32611, which are contained in the 'spatial_ref' variable. As such, I hope to reproject them both to 4326 before I can combine them effectively:

```
import xarray as xarr

raster1 = xarr.open_dataset("raster1.nc")
crs_1 = raster1['spatial_ref'].crs_wkt

raster2 = xarr.open_dataset("raster2.nc")
crs_2 = raster2['spatial_ref'].crs_wkt
```

> Raster1 contains pixels in an area SE of Tallahassee, FL

> Raster2 contains pixels in Northwestern Mexico

```
# Reproject both, first embedding the crs in xarray readable terms
## (without the .write_crs() call, it throws a MissingCRS error)

raster1 = raster1.rio.write_crs(crs_1).rio.reproject("EPSG:4326")
raster2 = raster2.rio.write_crs(crs_2).rio.reproject("EPSG:4326")
```

**Desired output** : Raster3, which contains the pixel labels in both of the above areas. This raster will ideally have a spatial extent defined by a bounding box containing both of the above regions.

I have tried the following, with no avail:

```
# This results in two distinct blobs with unclear significance to the original data 
raster3 = raster1.merge(raster2, join = 'outer', compat = 'override')


# This results in the same as above
raster3 = raster1.combine_first(raster2, join = 'outer', compat = 'override')
```

Merging the two rasters without reprojecting results in an amorphous blob.

[The data can be found at this google drive link.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yBl91JbHvnLckdqedtD97IkxE5bCoO34?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/merge.html

Comment: Thanks for the info! This function ended up working for my data type.